# Finding the size of table in java file

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In mysql command line, when i give the command:
select count(*) tables from users;
it works correctly. It gives me the size of the table.

But, i want to take the result in Java file.Thus i write in Java file the below code.But it doesn't work

```
public int f()
{
   ResultSet rs;
   int i;
   String query = "select count(*) tables from users";
   Statement st = this.con.createStatement();     //error
   rs = st.executeQuery(query);                   //error
   if(rs.next())                       //error
   {                   //error
    i = rs.getInt(1);                     //error
   }
  return i;    //error
}
```

How can i get the size of table in my Java file?

Comment: `rs.GetInt(1)`? Are you sure the query works?

Comment: it doesn't work , i'm sure . it is seen error in the only this line:i = rs.GetInt(1);

Comment: @user1308990 it is a compiler error as resultSet doesnt have GetInt(), it has getInt().  and also, you should invoke rs.next() before you retrievedata from the table.see my answer below.

Comment: Are you initializing the connection in this.con field correctly?

Comment: For christ sake. Errors are not just red flags. They come with a message, and happen either at runtime or compile time. Paste the exact error messages if you want help. You might also try to read them, understand them, and google them. "It doesn't work" is the poorest description of a problem you might give.

Comment: @atas , yes , i use the same in other functions and , there is no problem in any one. Only this one gives error

Comment: @user1308990 you were not handling SQLException in your code, check my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you never checked if the resultSet has data using its next() method.

From [ResultSet API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> The next method moves the cursor to the next row

```
public int f() throws SQLException {
//rest of your code
rs = st.executeQuery(query);
if(rs.next()){
i = rs.getInt(1);  
}
//rest of your code
}
```

also `ResultSet` has `getInt()` method not `GetInt()`, **java is case sensitive**.

**EDIT:** you have to **handle or declare SQLException(checked exception)** in your code. [Connection.createStatement()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement%28%29) would throw **SQLException**.

Comment: Ok. I changed the GetInt to getInt. But , now ,number of  errors increased.  i have edited the code

Comment: wow!!!!!!! thats the point which i should know!! very thanks , my friend. I didn't know that i must use SQLException. Am i right? Is it mandatory to use SQLException? Why and in which circumstances?

Comment: @user1308990 you are welcome, check this link to know about SQLException. it will let you know bout the database errors(if any) while connecting. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html

Comment: @user1308990 ofcourse, its a checked exception. so, you have to handle it. else you get a compiler error